# K8S API access with client certificate using python client

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

My purpose is to access my k8s API from a remote server using python client and client certificate, which is working with curl like this:

`curl --key /XXX/XXX.key --cert /XXX/XXX.crt --cacert /XXX/XXX.crt  https://api-k8s.XXX-XXX.XXX-XXX-/api/v1/pods`

My code is:

```
configuration = client.Configuration()

configuration.host = 'https://api-XXXX'
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = '/XXX/xxx.crt'
configuration.cert_file = '/XXX/xxx.crt'
configuration.key_file = '/XXX/xxx.key'
configuration.verify_ssl = True

v1 = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))

ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
```

but getting:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXX', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)'),))
```

If you have any ideas what I am missing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: https://interset.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011874548--SSL-CERTIFICATE-VERIFY-FAILED-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c-579-

Answer (score 3):

I just reproduced your scenario, and it works perfectly on python 2.7

This is the code:

```
from kubernetes import client

configuration = client.Configuration()

configuration.host = 'https://10.132.0.25:6443'
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = './ca.crt'
configuration.cert_file = './client.crt'
configuration.key_file = './client.key'
configuration.verify_ssl = True

v1 = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))

ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()

for i in ret.items:
  print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

...and the result:

```
$ python test.py 
192.168.171.66  kube-system     calico-kube-controllers-65b8787765-h7qv7
10.132.0.25     kube-system     calico-node-t4r4v
10.132.0.26     kube-system     calico-node-zbtjm
192.168.171.65  kube-system     coredns-5c98db65d4-rm2qh
192.168.171.67  kube-system     coredns-5c98db65d4-sr67s
10.132.0.25     kube-system     etcd-master
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-apiserver-master
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-controller-manager-master
10.132.0.26     kube-system     kube-proxy-759gn
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-proxy-v5hvc
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-scheduler-master
```

I created the cluster with kubeadm. It is running 1.15.3

```
$ kubectl get no
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master   Ready    master   41m   v1.15.3
worker   Ready    worker   41m   v1.15.3
```

Finally, client libraries:

```
$ pip freeze | grep -E 'kubernetes|requests'
kubernetes==10.0.1
requests==2.22.0
```

To troubleshoot more, more information is needed; regarding versions especially. But your code works fine.

**EDIT:** It worked on python3 as well:

```
$ python3 test.py 
192.168.171.66  kube-system     calico-kube-controllers-65b8787765-h7qv7
10.132.0.25     kube-system     calico-node-t4r4v
10.132.0.26     kube-system     calico-node-zbtjm
192.168.171.65  kube-system     coredns-5c98db65d4-rm2qh
192.168.171.67  kube-system     coredns-5c98db65d4-sr67s
10.132.0.25     kube-system     etcd-master
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-apiserver-master
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-controller-manager-master
10.132.0.26     kube-system     kube-proxy-759gn
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-proxy-v5hvc
10.132.0.25     kube-system     kube-scheduler-master
```

Comment: Thank you Suren for going into the trouble recreating the scenario, more info bellow:

I am trying to access the kubernetes API from an external server (not part of k8s) running:

`kubernetes==10.0.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
Python version is 2.7.5`


The remote k8s cluster is running `v1.12.5`, python k8s client is not installed there.

If you have any idea how to debug the output so I could troubleshoot further it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe the python client is not meant to work from outside the cluster!?

https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/csi-new-client-library-procedure.md#client-capabilities

`Client Capabilities

Works from within the cluster environment.`

Comment: I don't think so. The test I did was not from the cluster. It was in the same subnet.